# Angular-UI typeahead directive does not drop down

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using AngularUI [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive. Data-wise everything works fine; however, the dropbox is cut vertically, and a scrollbar shows up on the right. The image below shows what I mean. If I scroll down, I see all the values in the typeahead dropbox that I expect.

[image: Vertically bound region]

I tinkered with the styles and I see that .dropdown-menu style from AngularUI is defined as `position: absolute;` If I change it to `position: static;` the dropdown shows at full height; however, if I have a button below the input field - it shows to the right of the dropdown, instead of being overlayed by it. Again, a picture is worth a thousand words.
[image: Typeahead with position: static]

There are some styles at the "master page" level; but I have no idea what exactly causes such behavior. Clearly, I am running out of my CSS/Web design skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your container has `overflow: hidden` and of course it will cut typeahead's dropdown. In such cases you need to tell typeahead to append dropdown container to another parent container, typically `body`. For this you use additional config attribute `typeahead-append-to-body`. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="selected" 
       uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
       typeahead-append-to-body="true">
```

Comment: OMG - this is exactly what it was... and thank you for explaining *why*! Огромное спасибо :)

Comment: what does viewvalue do ?

Comment: @UsmanIqbal check typeahead documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Ftypeahead